# sleep() doesn't prevent maximum execution time

Tags: php, timeout

I am trying to import a large amount data and getting the time out error. Therefore, I tried to implement the `sleep()` function in my code.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $response as $id => $data )  {
    $i++;

    //Data Import Calls Here


    if ($i > 0 && $i % 5 == 0) { // After every 5 Loop Item Executions
        sleep(5); // Sleep for 5 seconds
    }
}
```

The 5 loop item is pretty less and shouldn't take the default max execution time (30 seconds) set in Apache. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are absolutely correct sleep does not. Try [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: sleep doesn't decrease the execution time. you should go a different way to achieve what you need.

Comment: `sleep` just pauses script for 5 seconds, it does not refresh execution time, script is still executed, but it just does __nothing__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct sleep does not. Try [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $response as $id => $data )  {
    $i++;

    //Data Import Calls Here


    if ($i > 0 && $i % 5 == 0) { // After every 5 Loop Item Executions
        set_time_limit (30);
    }
}
```